# C++ file binary mode copy?

Tags: c++, file, gcc, binary

I am trying to move d.pdf to new.pdf but after the move the new file is corrupted. Why ?

```
void move(){

    char x;
    ifstream myfile;
    ofstream g;
    myfile.open ("d.pdf", ios::in|ios::binary);
    g.open("new.pdf",ios::out|ios::binary);

    while(myfile>>x)
        g<<x;
}
```

Comment: You should rather use `read()` and `write()` than text based extraction/formatting for binary data.

Comment: Could you please give me an example ?

Comment: Of course: [`std::istream::read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read), [`std::ostream::write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

Comment: And an example of how to apply it on my little problem please ? :D

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you. The examples from the linked reference documentation should be fairly enough, that you can deduce the solution for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code is skipping white spaces.
Try:

```
myfile >> noskipws;
while(myfile >> x)
    g << x;
```

Comment: You can do this in one step: `g << myfile.rdbuf();`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, I adhere; I was answering to the 'why' part, but your line is better.

Comment: @user2391356 Well, thanks; I do really don't care if it works, that was only my 'why'. Anyway, accept the response if you please.